# nivo-lightbox plugin slideIn images onclick of next or previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I don't know how much people have used this **[plugin](http://dev7studios.com/products/nivo-lightbox-wordpress-plugin/)**, **[demo](http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-lightbox/)** but what I want is to change the default behavior of the plugin to something like `animated`. Currently, when you click on `next` or `previous` button, the images will be just appended without any visual animation. I just want to animate the images while appending! Can anybody suggest any good solution!! Below is the code where appending on the image takes place:

```
if (href.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/i) !== null) {
         var img = $('<img>', { src: href });
         img.one('load', function () {
               var wrap = $('<div class="nivo-lightbox-image" />');
               wrap.append(img); //gets appended here
               content.html(wrap).removeClass('nivo-lightbox-loading');
               // Vertically center images
               wrap.css({
                       'line-height': $('.nivo-lightbox-content').height() + 'px',
                       'height': $('.nivo-lightbox-content').height() + 'px' // For Firefox
               });
         }).each(function () {
                if (this.complete) $(this).load();
         });
}
```

**OK with any sort of animation**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just added a `fadeIn` after appending which seems to do some sort of animation although which is what I was accepting. Here is what I did:

```
wrap.append(img).fadeIn('4000');
```